# HQL Syntax to retrieve from a manytomany relationship

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two entities, Student and Teacher who have relationship many to many

Student.java:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="CROOS_STUDENT_TEACHER", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID"))

    private Collection<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
```

Teacher.java:

```
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
```

I'm currently trying to retrieve a list of sudents that are under a specific teacher useing the teacher's id like

```
select a from Student JOIN a.teachers p FROM Teacher where p.id = :id
```

and gave me an error

Ia also changed a little like removed FROM Teacher but it still doesn't work, any  other way I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct one should be:

```
select a from Student a JOIN a.teachers p where p.id = :id
```

Your query contains some syntax flaw like:

- Two `from` keyword inside single query
- You did not specify alias for `Student` but use `a`

Comment: in the log i don't see the @jointablevalue which is @JoinTable(name="CROOS_STUDENT_TEACHER instead i see the auto generated mapping table. the result is empty

Comment: can i make the selection comes from the teacher's class, to select his students??